# which is simple framework for WPF ?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, frameworks, desktop-application

I am doing lot of desktop application but using .Net WinForm.

But now for productivity as WPF provide lot of further. I am stating to doing development using WPF.

We are developing small application not very large but lot of enhancement comes for most of application.

**I am just want know which WPF framework/approach for WPF is good for me with considering following point**

1. **Framework is Simple to understand and manage**
2. **If support Fast Development its very good for us**
3. **New  enhancement its easy to add**
4. **Its Support UI management**
5. **Support new  further link LinQ, Entity Framework**

Comment: what kind of framework? M-V-VM? JSON? image procsessing? mapping? etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WPF, in general, doesn't really require a framework.  Choosing an appropriate framework really should happen after understanding the basics.

There are quite a few good, lightweight "frameworks" that help fill in the gaps, such as [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) and [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/).

However, if you're new to WPF, I'd start at the fundimentals, first. I wrote a series of articles on moving to [WPF from Windows Forms](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/) which explains how to think about WPF, and why you should try to think differently than you do in Windows Forms.  Often, when people first start using WPF, they make assumptions (like the requirement for a "framework") based on their Windows Forms experience, and waste a lot of time that could be better spent just building the application directly.

Comment: +1 I agree that it's good to get started w/o a Framework, but MVVM Light has some really helpful stuff and doesn't get in the way.

Answer (score 2):

To not scary you, but WPF It is not simple, especially if you are moving from Windows Forms. I, personally think it would be easier to someone who never did before desktop development, or at least WindowsForms dev.

So if you are searching for something to learn fast and boost your productivity, it's not about that.

Wpf is about testability, reliabity and scallability which is really beautiful and I strongly encorage you to begin to learn it. But consider that you will need understand and learn it, write basically more code then, may be, you did in WinForms. But this is a pay you have to pay for most advanced, flexible and powerful windows desktop dev framework I ever worked with.

In short, you have to learn it:)